# T-SQL to fill missing text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wondered if anyone can help me with this.

I have list of file names in a SQL Server table with some char truncated - like this:

```
1. ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360
2. ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.
3. ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.m
4. ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.mp
5. ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.mp4 (is the full name)
```

I need to fix the truncated items with full name.

Is there a SQL solution you can suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some more guidance on the logic you are expecting.

Comment: How can SQL ever know what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right, the correct name is somewhere in the table. Then you can try to get the maximum name the given name is a prefix of.

As a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (SELECT max(t2.nmuloc)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.nmuloc LIKE concat(t1.nmuloc, '%'))
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Or as an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET nmuloc = (SELECT max(t.nmuloc)
                            FROM elbat t
                            WHERE t.nmuloc LIKE concat(elbat.nmuloc, '%'));
```

Comment: had to filter out the null values from t1 otherwise the max value will show up on items that are null.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always suppose to be MP4 on the end and the only thing that is missing is the file extension then you can use `STUFF`. Otherwise, there isn’t a way to know what parts of the file are missing and it’d be far to broad to account for.

```
declare @table table (c varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360'),
('ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.'),
('ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.m'),
('ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.mp'),
('ykjxm130_2017j_vid105-640x360.mp4')

select
    isnull(stuff(c,charindex('.',c),4, '.mp4'),c + '.mp4')
from
    @table
```

So to fix your table it would be

```
Update yourTable
Set yourColumn = isnull(stuff(yourColumn,charindex('.',yourColumn),4, '.mp4'),yourColumn + '.mp4')
Where right(yourColumn,3) != ‘mp4’
```

Comment: Thanks. this works fine, but still there is an element of hardcode involved. For a quick fix it is great.